# Why is IsChecked property nullable boolean in WPF CheckBox?

Tags: wpf, checkbox

Is there a case when IsChecked property on WPF CheckBox null ?

I guess that will answer my question from title of question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is null when you don't know if its checked or not:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx

In many systems a checkbox like this is shaded instead of being checked.

Comment: I guess I just needed to look in official documentation... but I rely more on stackoverflow then msdn these days :)

Comment: This could be also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734227/wpf-checkbox-check-ischecked

Answer (score 12):

If that is the case then it's probably a three-state-checkbox, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate.aspx for an explaination.

Answer (score 5):

Null means the CheckBox is indeterminate (is neither blank nor checked, instead it either has a line through it, or the box has a gray box inside it)