# Why is CheckBox.IsChecked property Nullable<bool>?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Why is the `IsChecked` property of a checkbox control in WPF of type `bool?` (or `Nullable<bool>`). I mean how can a checkbox control have the value of `null`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is IsChecked property nullable boolean in WPF CheckBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032285/why-is-ischecked-property-nullable-boolean-in-wpf-checkbox)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx), the `IsChecked` property has three different possible states:

[image: CheckBox states]

So, when `IsChecked` is set to `null`, the check box will show an "indeterminate" state. This is commonly represented as a shaded, or greyed-out, control.

Answer (score 15):

Yes the null value exists and appears as a filled box. It indicates "Not Applicable" to the system.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes can have a 3rd, grayed, indeterminate state.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set the checkbox's property IsThreeState to true to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Because WPF supports binding. If we bind a DB boolean column value to a checkbox. That column may have True/False/Null values. That means it has three values for a boolean field. So the WPF UI also should handle the three state.