# howto resolve the ToggleSwitch isChecked "bool?" to c# with wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

i have a problem with the toggleSwitch from the silverlight toolkit. i need to set the isChecked from a settings class, but i dont know hot to get the `bool?` type which is required for this.

can someone give me a example how to set the isChecked property from c# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "?" qualifier on the bool type is shorthand for the [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) struct. All that means is that you can assign null to that particular variable. This often makes sense for something like a checkbox because a checkbox can have an indeterminate state (typically reflected by a "-" in the UI). In this case, the null value would reflect that indeterminate state. In code, you'd still set the IsChecked property like you would any other boolean.

```
toggleCheckBox.IsChecked = true; //check the checkbox
toggleCheckBox.IsChecked = false; //uncheck the checkbox
toggleCheckBox.IsChecked = null; //set the checkbox to indeterminate state
```

Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530065/wpf-why-is-checkbox-ischecked-property-nullablebool).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the toolkit, but `bool?` is the same as a normal `bool`, but it can also have the value `null`. So, `myToggle.IsChecked = true;` should work.

Comment: Also to read you can use the **HasValue** method to check whether the bool? is null or not. E.g.

if (myToggleSwitch.isChecked.HasValue && myToggleSwitch.IsChecked){
//Checked is True
}