# How to use Checked event properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, checked

I am trying to make app which will create excel sheets for multiple paths based on checkboxes.

Now i am trying create a method which will create files for checked CheckBoxes.

```
private void createFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < projektCheckBoxes.Count; ++index)
            {
                if (projektCheckBoxes[index].Checked)
                {
                    vytvorSoubor(index);
                    }
            }
```

My problem is that I am getting this fault:

> Error CS0079  The event 'ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the
>   left hand side of += or -=

I was searching through this forum so i tried `IsChecked` then i got this fault:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So i searched again and i found answer that `Checked` is an event and that I should use the `IsChecked` property like this...

```
  if (projektCheckBoxes[index].IsChecked ?"It's checked" : "Not checked")
```

but this didn't helped me either.

Could you please give me advise what I am doing wrong and how it should be correctly?

Thx!

Comment: i don't think that error comes from the code posted. It's probably in `vytvorSoubor`, so paste the code for that method

Comment: Try `if (projektCheckBoxes[index].IsChecked.Value)` instead.

Comment: just to be clear, are you using `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton` ?

Comment: Yes I am using `checkbox`. Now is my function `vytvorSoubor` total mess, but before i don't understand what can be wrong that I have issues with `checked'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'
```

It's up to you to decide how to treat the situation of an [indeterminate state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530078/6996876). If you choose to assimilate it to `false`, do for example

```
if (projektCheckBoxes[index].IsChecked??false)
```

Comment: This helped! THX!