# Is it possible to have a partially checked checkbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-interface, checkbox

I'm trying to work out whether it's possible to have the "partially checked" checkbox style in wpf.
I can't post a picture because I'm too new, but I'm talking about the checkboxes filled with green squares or suchlike.
Thanks

Comment: Hi jeff, this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343866/wpf-tristate-checkbox-how-to-change-the-order-of-the-states

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IsChecked` property [is nullable for CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032285/why-is-ischecked-property-nullable-boolean-in-wpf-checkbox), so if you bind to a nullable bool and assign null to it, the checkbox gets this partially checked style. [Here is a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530065/wpf-why-is-checkbox-ischecked-property-nullablebool/4530089#4530089)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`ToggleButton.IsThreeState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to support null as a value