# WPF Checkbox check IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

I'm not talking about an event handler for this, but rather a simple `If Statement` checking if the `CheckBox` has been checked. So far I have:

```
if (chkRevLoop.IsChecked == true){}
```

But that raises the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe there's something that I'm missing but your line works for me.

Comment: Most answers are fine, although to be exact, you'd need to specify what should happen when the checkbox is in indeterminate state (its `IsChecked` value would be `null`). Should it pass your condition or not?

Comment: @evanb This is no boolean. It is a nullable boolean. If you compare it with "==" it should work.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator). This operator returns right-hand operand  if the left-hand operand is null. So you can return `false` when the `CheckBox` is in [*indeterminate*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) state (when the value of `IsChecked` property is set to null):

```
if (chkRevLoop.IsChecked ?? false)
{

}
```

Answer (score 13):

You have to do this conversion from `bool?` to `bool`, to make it work:

```
if((bool)(chkRevLoop.IsChecked)){}
```

Since it is already a `bool` condition you need not to put true false because if it is true then only it will come inside this if condition else not.
so, no need to even put `chkRevLoop.IsChecked == true` here, you are by default asking `==true` by puttin `IsChecked`

Comment: "conversion"? I see just a cast.

Answer (score 11):

Multiple answers already but here is another alternative

```
if (chkRevLoop.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()) {}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`IsChecked` property of CheckBox is Nullable boolean.

```
public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
```

Create a Nullable boolean and equate it will work for you.

### Code

```
bool? NullableBool = chkRevLoop.IsChecked;
if(NullableBool == true)    {    }
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan please explain what is not making sense ?

Answer (score 4):

A `bool?` can be true, false or null, while `bool` can only be true or false.  `?` makes a type "nullable" and adds null as a possibility when it normally isn't, so you can probably just use

```
if ((bool)chkRevLoop.IsChecked == true){}
```

or

```
if (chkRevLoop.IsChecked == (bool?)true){}
```

to make it match up and work.  The second is probably better, since I don't know what would happen in the cast if IsChecked is null

Comment: If `IsChecked` is null, your first example will throw InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Figured it'd be bad.  Overall it seems strange that == isn't overloaded nullable mismatches.  Seems simple enough to default to a nullable cast or @user2946329 's answer.

Comment: I thought this should work too. In fact, OP's code works fine for me. I'm still not sure what's going on here...

Comment: You might be running this on a `WinForms` app (where CheckBox.Checked is `bool`, not `bool?`, while OP specifically said `WPF`. Just a thought.

Comment: Problem is the explicit cast. You can't cast null to bool. If you don't cast it will work. There's no problem in comparing null with true/false.

Answer (score 4):

Consider checking if the property has a value:

```
var isChecked = chkRevLoop.IsChecked.HasValue ? chkRevLoop.IsChecked : false;

if (isChecked){}
```

Comment: you don't need the `== true` you can just leave it at `if (isChecked)`

Answer (score 3):

One line is enough to check if the radio button is checked or not:

```
string status = Convert.ToBoolean(RadioButton.IsChecked) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked";
```

Comment: To who cast down vote, please explain why so I can enhance my answer?

Comment: I upvoted because you answered the question by using Convert. The question is not about the result type of bool or string. For me your answer looks perfect, its a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Nullable object. Because IsChecked property can be assigned to three different value: Null, true and false

```
Nullable<bool> isChecked  = new Nullable<bool>(); 
isChecked = chkRevLoop.IsChecked; 

if (isChecked.HasValue && isChecked.Value)
{


}
```

Comment: `if (isChecked.HasValue)` doesn't mean it'd be `true`. Having a `false` value would also pass your condition

Comment: That could be easily rewritten to `if(chkRevLoop.IsChecked ?? false) { }`, which is more concise and doesn't need all the boilerplating code :-)

Comment: Explicit solutions for all of us :)