# Checkbox uncheck event triggers checked and unchecked event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I come to problem and I dont know what causes,

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate><CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAssignedToThis,IsAsync=True}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
 </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

`Checked` and `Unchecked` events

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
    //some code
}

 private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("unChecked");
     //some code
  }
```

In `IsChecked` values are `bool` type and they working fine, since it marks `CheckBoxes`, but while I try to uncheck it triggers both checked and unchecked events. What did I miss?

Comment: the code you posted, it works fine.

Comment: You should also consider `indeterminate` state. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31734331/2946329

Comment: But why when I Uncheck it triggers uncheck > checked > unchecked events?

Comment: Also I mentioned my values are True/False assigined to isChecked, it was first idea I thought there is some values null, but I debuged them and I was wrong all values was a bool type no null type found. @S.Akbari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, I have reproduced your problem. Some tests show that problem in async binding.

I think it's a funny situation.

Let's start an explanation.
Application starts, checkbox unchecked. The user checks our element. Events step-by-step.

- Start set value - property setter invoked.
- End set value - property setter end work. A value was set.
- Checked - raised checked event.

Cool. User unchecked checkbox.

- Start set value - property setter started.
- Unchecked - raised unchecked event.
- Checked - setter property still busy. checkbox "IsChecked" property doesn't change and raise the checked event.
- End set value - setter has done his work. Value setted in binding property.
- Unchecked - because of the binding property changed to false raise unchecked event.

My code for testing.
ViewModel and code behind

```
    public class TestView
    {
        private bool _test;
        public bool TestProp
        {
            get => _test;
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start set value");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                _test = value;
                Console.WriteLine("End set value");
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestView();
        }

        private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checked");
        }

        private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unchecked");
        }
    }
```

Xaml part

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" IsChecked="{Binding TestProp, IsAsync=True}" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

You can use "Click" event (but if user will use keyboard for changing checkbox value click event won't raise) or call your event logic in property setter. It will be more appropriate for MVVM.

Comment: Indeed, removing Asynch it fixes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this happening and having two events pop up every time I'd suggest setting up the same handler for both events with a single change signal as follows:

```
<CheckBox Checked="CheckBoxChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxChanged"/>

private void CheckBoxChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("State has been changed.");
}
```