# Programmatically created CheckBox does not fire Checked/Unchecked events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application that uses a "frame" for multi-page navigation. One of that pages creates a series of `CheckBoxes` and adds a couple of handlers (`Checked`/`Unchecked`) for each checkbox created. The `CheckBoxes` work as intended and are programmatically accessible, they can be checked or unchecked by click but none of the two events is ever fired if I click.

Here is the creation of the `CheckBoxes`:

```
ModuleStackpanels[i].Children.Add(ModuleCheckBoxes[i]);
StackPanel.SetZIndex(ModuleCheckBoxes[i], 2);
ModuleCheckBoxes[i].Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(ModuleCheckBoxClick);
ModuleCheckBoxes[i].Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(ModuleCheckBoxClick);
```

Where I go from 0 to 30. Then I have the handler:

```
private void ModuleCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int CheckBoxCounter = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        if (ModuleCheckBoxes[i].IsChecked == true) CheckBoxCounter++;
    }

    if(CheckBoxCounter > 1)
    {
        Button_QueryStatus.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

But nothing is fired.
Someone has got an idea?

Comment: As an aside note: you should also be aware of the **indeterminate** state of WPF `CheckBox`. Have a look at this answer to know more https://stackoverflow.com/a/31734331/2946329

Comment: You can also use `sender`. Have a look at this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528628/2946329

Comment: Are you sure the events aren't fired? I can't recreate the problem, maybe just the code inside ModuleCheckBoxClick doesn't work as intended?

Comment: @MaxB, i put a breakpoint inside the ModuleCheckBoxClick function and it stops only if i change the checkboxes state via program.  If i click on them it won't stop.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thank you! But i guess I can't use the sender if no event is firing. I'll read more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! Not all the checkboxes had the event handler because of a fault in the creation of the buttons. 3 on 30 had it, and these buttons represented a different kind of item.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `CheckedChanged` instead of `Checked` and `Unchecked`.

For example:

```
public bool checkedthecheckbox { get; set; }

CheckBox testchbox = new CheckBox();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testchbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(testchbox_CheckedChanged);
}

void testchbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (testchbox.Checked)
        checkedthecheckbox = true;
    else
        checkedthecheckbox = false;
}
```

In your case:

```
ModuleStackpanels[i].Children.Add(ModuleCheckBoxes[i]);
StackPanel.SetZIndex(ModuleCheckBoxes[i], 2);
ModuleCheckBoxes[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ModuleCheckBoxClick);

private void ModuleCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int CheckBoxCounter = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        if (ModuleCheckBoxes[i].IsChecked == true) CheckBoxCounter++;
    }

    if(CheckBoxCounter > 1)
    {
        Button_QueryStatus.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to include checkedchanged but it doesn't appear in the event list. i even tried to add a "using System.Web.UI.WebControls" but it doesn't work. How can I add it? I miss some references?

Comment: Strange, if you see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) for example the namespace you add is correct.

Comment: Try with  `IsChecked`. If it works, I'll update the answer. Unfortunately I can't try the code right now.

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm building a Desktop application but I'm not sure it works like this. I'll try today! Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a WPF application?

Comment: Yes sorry, a WPF desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with a similar issue on a WPF app that I did not write the front end for and here it came down to: `Checked` and similar event handlers will fire if the checkbox is triggered manually or programmatically. Other types are not guaranteed in the same way if you are changing the checkbox by setting to `IsChecked`.

ex. in my case, they attempted to use a `Clicked` event handler which would only fire from actual user interaction and not programmatic change, which makes perfect sense because setting the IsChecked status is truly *not* a click event (even though both can potentially check or uncheck the checkbox)